# Создание пользователя

Tags: php, laravel

Проект на laravel. Используется laravel passport. Хочу отловить создание пользователя с уже существующим в базе email. 
Обернул создание в try/catch:

```
  try {
        $user = User::create($input);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        \Log::info($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

Получаем следующее описание ошибки:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint
>   failed: users.email (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "is_admin",
>   "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (user52, 0,
>   user52, $2y$10$48o0auvS7tamppkvu7fiSO0f74nwMStGeUfurJDG0KGm4xN1/oP8u,
>   2020-02-12 12:37:45, 2020-02-12 12:37:45))

Как мне понять, что ошибка произошла именно из-за нарушения уникальности поля email ? Искать в `$ex->getMessage()` подстроку `"UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email"?` Но если в следующей версии формат описания ошибки измениться? Как сделать это понадежнее?

Comment: Надо использовать валидацию. В документации написано как: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic
Без запроса к базе не обойтись. Экономить на запросах такого типа - экономить на спичках.

Comment: Посмотрите внутрь `$ex`, там как минимум есть code. Мне кажется он для разных ошибок разный.

Comment: Рассматривал данный вариант, не вполне понятен механизм формирования кода, как он зависит от типа ошибки, наименования поля и насколько он постоянен от версии к версии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отловить создание пользователя с уже существующим имэйлом, надо сперва попробовать выбрать пользователя с таким имэйлом. Если пользователь найден, значит имэйл уже занят.

Comment: Не хотелось создавать лишний запрос к базе, когда этого можно избежать.

Comment: @ВладКолестников в данном случае запрос совсем не лишний. Теоретически можно завязаться на код ошибки в сообщении базы данных, но это будет костыль несоразмерный полученной выгоде.

Comment: Все думают, что это костыль?

Comment: Ещё возможен хак с insert on duplicate key update в mysql. Из доки "With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values". Делать так не надо :-)

Comment: Это плохой ответ. По логике Лары нужно использовать валидатор, и внезапно он имеет все что нужно, включая сообщения об ошибке. Как правильно сделать написано в доке к Ларе https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: @TotalPusher согласен про валидатор. Я хотел пояснить в чём заключается проверка. Валидатор тоже сделает запрос в бд.

Comment: @ВладКолестников Скорее всего не все считают это костылём (хаком, если вы делаете это для оптимизации), но вероятно многие. Сообщение об ошибке специфично для конкретной базы; прежде чем попасть в ваш код, оно просачивается через несколько слоёв фрэймворка и может меняться; парсинг сообщения об ошибке (даже простой strpos) не выражает замысел пярмо и требует пояснений.

Comment: Нет смысла оптимизировать досрочно, тем более почта  пользователя будет индексирована через UNIQUE, и запрос не займёт много времени или ресурсов.